# Form with JavaScript calculations sending missing data (only in some cases)

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have the below form on my website that does live calculations using the Javascript code below and sends the data through PHP.

The form works fine and successfully sends the calculated figures in most cases. But sometimes (may be 1 out of 5 submissions) the values are missing, for example:

**FLOWERS:**
Size: 50
Price: MRP 175.00
Quantity: 5
litres: **0.250** **– This is fine!**

Normally, the above comes correctly as below:

**FLOWERS:**
Size: 50
Price: MRP 175.00
Quantity: 5
litres: **0.000** – This is wrong and missing!

Can this be the case if JavaScript is disabled in the user's browser?

**HTML CODE:** – [LINK FOR HTML CODE](http://drearth.in/order.html)

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
    function calculate() {

/* FLOWERS */   
        var flowersSize = flsz.options[flsz.selectedIndex].value;
        if (flowersSize == 50) {
            flpr.value = 175;
            flowersPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(175 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            flpr.value = "MRP"+" "+flowersPrice;            
        } else if (flowersSize == 200) {
            flpr.value = 599;
            flowersPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(599 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            flpr.value = "MRP"+" "+flowersPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");         
        } else if (flowersSize == 500) {
            flpr.value = 1299;
            flowersPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(1299 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            flpr.value = "MRP"+" "+flowersPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");         
        } else if (flowersSize == 1000) {
            flpr.value = 2399;
            flowersPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(2399 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            flpr.value = "MRP"+" "+flowersPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");         
        } else if (flowersSize == 5000) {
            flpr.value = 10999;
            flowersPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(10999 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            flpr.value = "MRP"+" "+flowersPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }

/* CEREALS */
        var cerealsSize = cesz.options[cesz.selectedIndex].value;
        if (cerealsSize == 50) {
            cepr.value = 199;
            cerealsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(199 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            cepr.value = "MRP"+" "+cerealsPrice;            
        } else if (cerealsSize == 200) {
            cepr.value = 699;
            cerealsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(699 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            cepr.value = "MRP"+" "+cerealsPrice;            
        } else if (cerealsSize == 500) {
            cepr.value = 1599;
            cerealsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(1599 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            cepr.value = "MRP"+" "+cerealsPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");         
        } else if (cerealsSize == 1000) {
            cepr.value = 2899;
            cerealsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(2899 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            cepr.value = "MRP"+" "+cerealsPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");     
        } else if (cerealsSize == 5000) {
            cepr.value = 12999;
            cerealsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(12999 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            cepr.value = "MRP"+" "+cerealsPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }

/* VEGETABLES */    
        var vegetablesSize = vesz.options[vesz.selectedIndex].value;
        if (vegetablesSize == 50) {
            vepr.value = 225;
            vegetablesPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(225 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            vepr.value = "MRP"+" "+vegetablesPrice;     
        } else if (vegetablesSize == 200) {
            vepr.value = 799;
            vegetablesPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(799 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            vepr.value = "MRP"+" "+vegetablesPrice;     
        } else if (vegetablesSize == 500) {
            vepr.value = 1799;
            vegetablesPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(1799 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            vepr.value = "MRP"+" "+vegetablesPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");          
        } else if (vegetablesSize == 1000) {
            vepr.value = 3399;
            vegetablesPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(3399 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            vepr.value = "MRP"+" "+vegetablesPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");          
        } else if (vegetablesSize == 5000) {
            vepr.value = 14999;
            vegetablesPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(14999 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            vepr.value = "MRP"+" "+vegetablesPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }

/* FRUITS */        
        var fruitsSize = frsz.options[frsz.selectedIndex].value;
        if (fruitsSize == 50) {
            frpr.value = 249;
            fruitsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(249 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            frpr.value = "MRP"+" "+fruitsPrice;         
        } else if (fruitsSize == 200) {
            frpr.value = 899;
            fruitsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(899 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            frpr.value = "MRP"+" "+fruitsPrice;         
        } else if (fruitsSize == 500) {
            frpr.value = 1999;
            fruitsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(1999 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            frpr.value = "MRP"+" "+fruitsPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");          
        } else if (fruitsSize == 1000) {
            frpr.value = 3699;
            fruitsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(3699 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            frpr.value = "MRP"+" "+fruitsPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");          
        } else if (fruitsSize == 5000) {
            frpr.value = 16999;
            fruitsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(16999 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            frpr.value = "MRP"+" "+fruitsPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }

/* PLANTATIONS */       
        var plantationsSize = plsz.options[plsz.selectedIndex].value;
        if (plantationsSize == 50) {
            plpr.value = 275;
            plantationsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(275 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            plpr.value = "MRP"+" "+plantationsPrice;            
        } else if (plantationsSize == 200) {
            plpr.value = 999;
            plantationsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(999 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            plpr.value = "MRP"+" "+plantationsPrice;        
        } else if (plantationsSize == 500) {
            plpr.value = 2199;
            plantationsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(2199 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            plpr.value = "MRP"+" "+plantationsPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");         
        } else if (plantationsSize == 1000) {
            plpr.value = 3999;
            plantationsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(3999 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            plpr.value = "MRP"+" "+plantationsPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");         
        } else if (plantationsSize == 5000) {
            plpr.value = 17999;
            plantationsPrice = parseFloat(Math.round(17999 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            plpr.value = "MRP"+" "+plantationsPrice.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }

        var flowersQuantity = flqt.options[flqt.selectedIndex].value;
        var cerealsQuantity = ceqt.options[ceqt.selectedIndex].value;
        var vegetablesQuantity = veqt.options[veqt.selectedIndex].value;
        var fruitsQuantity = frqt.options[frqt.selectedIndex].value;
        var plantationsQuantity = plqt.options[plqt.selectedIndex].value;

        var flowersLitres = flowersSize * flowersQuantity / 1000;
        var cerealsLitres = cerealsSize * cerealsQuantity / 1000;   
        var vegetablesLitres = vegetablesSize * vegetablesQuantity / 1000;
        var fruitsLitres = fruitsSize * fruitsQuantity / 1000;  
        var plantationsLitres = plantationsSize * plantationsQuantity / 1000;

        flowersLitres = parseFloat(Math.round(flowersLitres * 100) / 100).toFixed(3);
        cerealsLitres = parseFloat(Math.round(cerealsLitres * 100) / 100).toFixed(3);
        vegetablesLitres = parseFloat(Math.round(vegetablesLitres * 100) / 100).toFixed(3);
        fruitsLitres = parseFloat(Math.round(fruitsLitres * 100) / 100).toFixed(3);
        plantationsLitres = parseFloat(Math.round(plantationsLitres * 100) / 100).toFixed(3);   

        fllt.value = flowersLitres;
        celt.value = cerealsLitres;
        velt.value = vegetablesLitres;
        frlt.value = fruitsLitres;
        pllt.value = plantationsLitres;

        var totalAmount =  flowersQuantity * flowersPrice + cerealsQuantity * cerealsPrice + vegetablesQuantity * vegetablesPrice + fruitsQuantity * fruitsPrice + plantationsQuantity * plantationsPrice;

        totalAmount = parseFloat(Math.round(totalAmount * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

        tamt.value = "MRP"+" "+totalAmount.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
    <?php

if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['address'])) {
    die('Error: Missing variables');
}

$name=$_POST['name'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$telephone=$_POST['telephone'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$state=$_POST['state'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$pincode=$_POST['pincode'];
$total_amount=$_POST['total_amount'];

$flowers_size=$_POST['flowers_size'];
$flowers_price=$_POST['flowers_price'];
$flowers_quantity=$_POST['flowers_quantity'];
$flowers_litres=$_POST['flowers_litres'];

$cereals_size=$_POST['cereals_size'];
$cereals_price=$_POST['cereals_price'];
$cereals_quantity=$_POST['cereals_quantity'];
$cereals_litres=$_POST['cereals_litres'];

$vegetables_size=$_POST['vegetables_size'];
$vegetables_price=$_POST['vegetables_price'];
$vegetables_quantity=$_POST['vegetables_quantity'];
$vegetables_litres=$_POST['vegetables_litres'];

$fruits_size=$_POST['fruits_size'];
$fruits_price=$_POST['fruits_price'];
$fruits_quantity=$_POST['fruits_quantity'];
$fruits_litres=$_POST['fruits_litres'];

$plantations_size=$_POST['plantations_size'];
$plantations_price=$_POST['plantations_price'];
$plantations_quantity=$_POST['plantations_quantity'];
$plantations_litres=$_POST['plantations_litres'];


$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$to="customercare@drearth.in";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";  
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";  
$headers = 'From: '.$_POST['name'].' <'.$_POST['email'].'>';

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$subject='Order from '.$name."\n\n\n";

$body.="<h2>DETAILS:</h2>"."";

$body.='Customer Name: <b>'.$name."</b><br>\n";
$body.='Mobile No: <b>'.$mobile."</b><br>\n";
$body.='Telephone No: <b>'.$telephone."</b><br>\n";
$body.='Email Address: <b>'.$email."</b><br>\n";
$body.='Address: <b>'.$address."</b><br>\n";
$body.='State: <b>'.$state."</b><br>\n";
$body.='City: <b>'.$city."</b><br>\n";
$body.='Pin code: <b>'.$pincode."</b><br><br>\n\n";

$body.="<h2>VARIANTS:</h2>"."";

$body.="<b>FLOWERS:</b>"."<br>\n";
$body.='Size: '.$flowers_size."<br>\n";
$body.='Price: '.$flowers_price."<br>\n";
$body.='Quantity: '.$flowers_quantity."<br>\n";
$body.='litres: '.$flowers_litres."<br><br>\n\n";

$body.="<b>CEREALS:</b>"."<br>\n";
$body.='Size: '.$cereals_size."<br>\n";
$body.='Price: '.$cereals_price."<br>\n";
$body.='Quantity: '.$cereals_quantity."<br>\n";
$body.='Litres: '.$cereals_litres."<br><br>\n\n";

$body.="<b>VEGETABLES:</b>"."<br>\n";
$body.='Size: '.$vegetables_size."<br>\n";
$body.='Price: '.$vegetables_price."<br>\n";
$body.='Quantity: '.$vegetables_quantity."<br>\n";
$body.='Litres: '.$vegetables_litres."<br><br>\n\n";

$body.="<b>FRUITS:</b>"."<br>\n";
$body.='Size: '.$fruits_size."<br>\n";
$body.='Price: '.$fruits_price."<br>\n";
$body.='Quantity: '.$fruits_quantity."<br>\n";
$body.='Litres: '.$fruits_litres."<br><br>\n\n";

$body.="<b>PLANTATIONS:</b>"."<br>\n";
$body.='Size: '.$plantations_size."<br>\n";
$body.='Price: '.$plantations_price."<br>\n";
$body.='Quantity: '.$plantations_quantity."<br>\n";
$body.='Litres: '.$plantations_litres."<br><br>\n\n";

$body.="<h2>AMOUNT:</h2>"."";
$body.='Total Price: <b>'.$total_amount."</b><br><br><br><br>\n\n\n\n";
$body.='IP address of the submitter: '."\n".$ip."\n";

$headers  = "From: $email <$email>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'bcc: xxx@gmail.com' . "\r\n";

if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    header("Location: http://www.drearth.in/confirmation.html"); 
} else {
    echo "Something has gone wrong! Please try again!"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Please don't do the whole "please please please help mee" thing. It's not helping your case at all.

Comment: Hmmm okay I take your advise :) Can you please advise something that may help?

Comment: In answer to your question - probably Yes. It is possible to submit the form when Javascript is disabled and I guess your calculations will therefore not work... You ought to do the majority of the calculations at the backend

Comment: Thanks RamRaider :) Can you please suggest me the best way forward? As in what technology of coding to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little bit of refactoring of your original javascript function - I think it is correct but you might ( if you want ) need to go through carefully to see that it is right. To address the issue of blank values every so often.... You should not allow the form to be submitted if javascript is not enabled - to achieve this actually use javascript to submit the form rather than a simple submit button perhaps. Also, you might want to recompute the values in php and check they match?

```
/* to format a number with correct separators ~ comma */
function format_thousands(n){
    var s=(''+n).split('.');
    s[0]=s[0].split('').reverse().join('').match(/\d{1,3}/gi).join(',').split('').reverse().join('');
    return(s.join('.'));
}

/* utility to get the value from select menu */
function gsv(n){
    var n=typeof(n)=='object' && n.nodeType==1 ? n : document.getElementById(n);
    return n.options[n.selectedIndex].value;
}

function calculate() {
    var matrix={
        flowers:{
            size:'flsz',
            qty:'flqt',
            txt:'flpr',
            ltr:'fllt',
            values:{50:175,200:599,500:1299,1000:2399,5000:10999}
        },
        cereals:{
            size:'cesz',
            qty:'ceqt',
            txt:'cepr',
            ltr:'celt',
            values:{50:199,200:699,500:1599,1000:2899,5000:12999},
        },
        vegetables:{
            size:'vesz',
            qty:'veqt',
            txt:'vepr',
            ltr:'velt',
            values:{50:225,200:799,500:1799,1000:3399,5000:14999}
        },
        fruits:{
            size:'frsz',
            qty:'frqt',
            txt:'frpr',
            ltr:'frlt',
            values:{50:249,200:899,500:1999,1000:3699,5000:16999}
        },
        plantations:{
            size:'plsz',
            qty:'plqt',
            txt:'plpr',
            ltr:'pllt',
            values:{50:275,200:999,500:2199,1000:3999,5000:17999}
        }
    };
    var totals={total:0};

    for( var glitch in matrix ){
        var keys=Object.keys( matrix[ glitch ] );
        var size=gsv( matrix[ glitch ].size );
        var qty=gsv( matrix[ glitch ].qty );
        var value=matrix[ glitch ].values[ size ];
        var price = parseFloat( Math.round( value * 100 ) / 100 ).toFixed(2);
        var litres = parseFloat( Math.round( ( ( size * qty ) / 1000 ) * 100 ) / 100 ).toFixed(3);

        totals[ glitch ]={ litres:litres, price:price, mrp:'MRP '+price.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") };
        totals.total += qty * price;

        document.getElementById( matrix[ glitch ].txt ).value=totals[ glitch ].mrp;
        document.getElementById( matrix[ glitch ].ltr ).value=litres;
    }
    totals.total=parseFloat( Math.round( totals.total * 100 ) / 100 ).toFixed(2);
    totals.totalmrp = 'MRP ' + totals.total.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

    document.getElementById('tamt').value=totals.totalmrp;
    /* do something with result ? */
    return totals;
}
```

You would probably want to change your form so that the action is only set to the correct php script when the form is actually submitted. The action is changed via javascript just before submission.

```
<form autocomplete="off" class="form" name="form" method="post" action="order.html" onsubmit="return submitform(event)">

    <!-- lots of other form content -->

    <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' tabindex='29' class='button' id='subform' name='subform'>
</form>
```

The submission only occurs then if the function `submitform` returns true

```
function submitform(event){
    /* example only - add own checks */
    var checks_ok=false;
    var form=typeof(event.target)!='undefined' ? event.target : event.srcElement;
    /* Perform various checks on form fields to ensure fields are not empty, or contain invalid values etc */

    /* if ok, set checks_ok to true */
    checks_ok=true;

    if( checks_ok ){
        form.setAttribute('action','/php/order-form.php');
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**My Version:**

```
function submitform(event){
    var checks_ok=false;
    var flq=document.getElementById("flqt").value;
    var ceq=document.getElementById("ceqt").value;
    var veq=document.getElementById("veqt").value;
    var frq=document.getElementById("frqt").value;
    var plq=document.getElementById("plqt").value;
    var quantity=flq+ceq+veq+frq+plq;

    if(quantity==0){
        alert("Please select quantity");
        checks_ok=false;
        return false;
    } 
    if(checks_ok=true){
        form.setAttribute('action','http://www.drearth.in/php/order-form-test.php');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks RamRaider for applying some thought to it. So if I just plug the above code into my html, will that be good? I'm trying now...

Comment: Okay RamRaider, I tried it but it's not updating the 'Litres' and 'Total Price'!!!

Comment: I hadn't factored that field into the funcion... will have a look but should be pretty straightforward

Comment: Thanks mate... Your code looks pro dude... I really hope it solves the problem of empty values... I'll really appreciate your help...

Comment: As I mentioned, to avoid the empty values you need to change the submit button to a simple button and enforce submission via javascript  ( it can still be modified on the client side but it is a start!). Then check again in php, compare the values and if they match then all is good. The above has been changed to add the total price and update the litres.. think it is correct!

Comment: You're a genius buddy! But please can you further explain how do I enforce submission via javascript and compare the values in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

please use loops for printing item wise list otherwise it's not a good approach.
you just write a common function to calculate your MRP like this.

```
<script> 
 function calculate(item,itmval,MRPDOMID){
  item.value = itmval;
        Price = parseFloat(Math.round(899 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        MRPDOMID.value = "MRP"+" "+Price;  
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Hi Anuraj... Thanks for answering, but I'm not sure if it's in context to my problem. May be you are right but I hope you see that there is a specific price per item per quantity. So can you please elaborate upon your solution?